# Getting error while connecting postgres to php

Tags: php, postgresql

Hi i am trying to connect postgres server with PHP onm windows with xaampp. I have enabled the extension php_pgsql.dll in php.ini. I have also give the libpq.dll path to httpd.conf.
But still i am getting error Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_pconnect() Any solution

Comment: IN phpinfo i not getting postgres module.

Comment: Have you tried restarting apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used postgres9.2 bin folder and load the libpq.dll in httpd.conf It solved my problem. I think there is some version compatibility first i was using 9.4 postgre bin files which was not working.
I added this line to Loadfile "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin\libpq.dll" httpd.conf
And remove ; from extension=php_pgsql.dll
After restarted the sever solved my problem.